# Pressure / Gauss Curvature relation in Plate theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

An approximate expression for 1d shallow beam curvature $y''$ used in structural engineering is generalized by Euler-Bernoulli Law for constant curvature more exactly in non-linear theory as

$$ \frac {y''}{(1+y{'2})^{3/2}}= \kappa=\frac {M}{EI};~ $$

It is noted that the moment curvature proportionality  depends on material property  $ EI $ of the beam alone.

In 2d plate and surface theory we have the relation for $ p/Dt $ ( where $p$ is normal pressure , $D$ is flexural rigidity per unit plate edge length and $t$ plate thickness) fom Sophie Germain  and von Kármán

$$\frac{\partial ^{4}w}{\partial x^{4}}+\frac{2 ~\partial ^{4}w} {\partial x^{2} \partial y^{2}}+\frac{\partial ^{4}w}{\partial y^{4}}=\frac{K}{t} =\frac{p}{D}; $$

The former is from her work on elastic plate vibrations in 1821 and the latter from his  strain compatibility condition in 2d generalized up from Kirchhoff's assumption in elementary 1d beam bendings (that plane sections remain plane during deformation).

It is noted that the pressure-Gauss curvature proportionality $D$  is a material property of the plate alone.

Is the above relation accurate, or does K need any modification factor?

Just as $M-\kappa $ are bound together in 1d Euler-Bernoulli ode I had expected to find $ p-K $ relation as a pde  even in text books of civil or structural engg.

But I could not find references or similar research. So I am  requesting for help  as access to literature relating pressure $p$ to the elastically developed $K $ either in theory or experiment is limited for me.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: see for example these [lecture notes](https://ocw.snu.ac.kr/sites/default/files/NOTE/Lecture%2003%20Plate%20Bending.pdf); there should be no factor $1/t$ and a derivative $\partial^4 w/\partial y^4$ is missing.

Comment: Thanks, corrected typo, is it ok? I think it is not ok, would re-edit the question bringinging in stress Function $F$ for membrane effect.

Comment: yes, ths is correct; see also  https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/jiaweiyang/files/4_bending_of_plates.pdf (bottom of page 5, where $D$ is denoted as $K$)

Comment: Thanks, I mean is the first part  $ K =\dfrac{p t}{D} $ correct?